# Pull OpportunityContactRole value into VisualForce Template related to an Invoice

Tags: visualforce, email-template, lookup, related-list

We're setting up a workflow to notify the finance department when an Opportunity owner flags an invoice as "ready to be sent".

I've got a VF email template, relatedTo="invoice", and I want to pull out:

```
{!relatedTo.Opportunity__r.OpportunityContactRoles}
```

and then cycle through that to find the billing contact.

When I do that, I get the error:
*Aggregate Relationship is used in an unsupported complex expression*

I've done some digging and understand that there is limit to the depth you can traverse in parent/child relationships, but is there any other workaround? It is possible to include some kind of lookup field on the Invoice object (which is custom), to pull or make the OpportunityContactRoles directly related to the invoice object so it can be referenced directly.

Any ideas / experience with this?

Sample Code when Nested:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!relatedTo.Opportunity__r.OpportunityContactRoles}" var="opp">
    <apex:repeat value="{!opp.Contact}" var="cx">
        {!cx.Name}
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:repeat>
```

Comment: the expression you are using returns a list.  Are you using it in a VF repeat or pageblocktable or datatable component `value=` attribute?

Comment: I've tried it putting it in a repeat block, and even nesting to see if that would solve it, but as soon as I try to reference the Contact in any way, it breaks. I've updated my post with a sample from the nested version, which throws the same error as above.

Comment: `opp.Contact` wouldn't work as that is an object, not a list

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that SOQL doesn't allow you to go up to a parent and then down to a child in a single expression.

`Opportunity` is parent of `Invoice`, `OpportunityContactRoles` is child of `Opportunity`

Your solution will require a custom VF component with its own controller that you'll insert into your VF template

```
<c:OCR oId="{!relatedTo.opportunity__c}"/>
```

The component's VF markup will be

```
<apex:component controller="OpportunityOcrController" access="global">
  <apex:attribute name="oId" assignTo="{!oppoId}" type="id" description="Opportunity id"/>

  <apex:repeat value="{!ocrs}" var="ocr">
    <apex:outputField value="{!ocr.role}"/>
  </apex:repeat>
</apex:component>
```

The `OpportunityOcrController` has a method `getOcrs()` that uses the value of property `oppoId` to retrieve the OCRs for that Oppo